# Python - How to optimize einsum?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-einsum

I am trying to optimize my code and I don't know if I am already at the limit.

Here is my problem: I am solving the equation of motion for multiple trajectories. What this means is that I have an array `t_list=[0,....,T]` with `Nmax+1` elements. At each time `t_i`, I have `Mmax` independent trajectories. What I have are two matrices A and B such that `A[:,:,t_i,m]` and `B[:,:,t_i,m]` such that the first two elements are the 2D matrix elements. The 3rd label is for the time evolution, and the last is for the different trajectories. My task is to take the tensor product of these matrices and average over all possible trajectories. This is what I can do:

```
for n_i,n in enumerate(t_list):
    C=np.einsum('ij...,kl...->ikjl...',A[:,:,n_i,:],B[:,:,n_i,:],optimize="greedy").reshape(1024,1024,Mmax).mean(axis=2)
```

Where 1024x1024 is just the dimension of my matrices. What I am basically doing here is that for each time step, I calculate the tensor product using einsum, I reshape it and then I take the average over the axis I need.

Part of my problem is that I need to average over a lot of trajectories, `Mmax=10000`, which makes this whole operation quite slow. I was thinking about paralelizing it, but I am a bit stuck as to how to do it.

Is there some way to optimize my code, or have I done something I could be doing better

Comment: try parallelizing using `Numba`, check this [link](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/parallel.html)

Comment: @AliEnt unfortunately, Numba does is not compatible with einsum, so I would have to find a different approach

Comment: cupy supports [einsum](https://docs.cupy.dev/en/stable/reference/generated/cupy.einsum.html) if you have a CUDA supported GPU on your device, you can use `cupy` or you can use google colab

Comment: @AliEnt thanks for the reference, I was unaware of this package. Let me ask this to be clear: You are suggesting using CuPy+Numba to optimize the operation, or just cupy.einsum is enough?

Comment: your welcome. they are two different packages. Numba is using jit to compile some parts of your python code to accelerate it.  Cupy is a replacement for Numpy and Scipy to use CUDA GPUs. einsum is not supported by Numba so your only option is Cupy. acceleration rate is case-based. you have to check it.